# Ruby cucumber rspec Poltergeist test fails to find text inside an iframe

Tags: ruby, cucumber, poltergeist

I have a Ruby cucumber poltergeist test which constantly fails when running on the CI Jenkins server with the following error but runs ok locally.

```
expected to find text "Medals table final positions" in "" 
(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

This text is inside an iframe the piece of code which does this verification is

```
if page.has_css?("iframe") #Check inside iframe if present
        page.within_frame 0 do
           expect(page).to have_content(text) 
     end
```

Does anyone knows what can it be the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The `in ""` the error message would tend to imply one of 3 things

1. You're in the wrong iframe - if the page only has one iframe that can't be it
2. The iframe doesn't actually have content - Print out what `page.html` is inside the iframe
3. The iframe hasn't loaded yet - Check the driver network traffic to see if the page actually loaded, and make sure the URL the iframe is loading is actually reachable

I guess one other option could be you're running a different version of PhantomJS on Jenkins than you are locally (and are using something in your page/frame that isn't supported by an older version), but I assume you've already checked that.